# What is the best way to play a sound with the least amount of delay possible, in Swift/Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, audio, avaudioplayer

I am experiencing a slight delay between UIButton press and sound output (it seems to average about 0.05 seconds). I am currently implementing AVAudioPlayer. Is there a best way to play a sound instantaneously? I scoured the Internet but can't find a concrete answer.

For reference, my (simplified) code is as follows:

```
// Get sound url
let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: file, ofType: type)!)
  
// Audio Player
var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
      
do {
    // Create audio player
    audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)          
} 
catch let errMsg as NSError {
    print("AVAudioPlayer error: \(errMsg.localizedDescription)")
}

// Prepare audio player to play
audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()

//...

@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    audioPlayer.play()
}
```

Comment: Is the delay noticeable on a physical device, or just the simulator? They way I do it is similar, but I experience no delay on a physical device.

Comment: AVAudioPlayer is not good for low latency applications. See the first paragraph in the class documentation.

Comment: @LucasDahl I experienced the delay while testing on a physical device.

Comment: @jaket Ahh... I didn't see that! Thanks for pointing that out. So what would you recommend instead for applications that require low latency? Is AVAudioEngine the fastest?

Comment: AVAudioEngine can certainly be faster. You can get close to realtime but with extra code complexity.

Comment: @jaket So is AVAudioEngine the fastest or at least the recommended way for realtime sound effects? Or are there other options that are recommended as well?